# Rebuilding of xDB index doesn't start after scaling up Azure Search

Tags: xdb, azure-search

We have an issue with Sitecore xDB index in Azure Search on Sitecore 9.1.1.

- Recently we tried to rebuild `xDB index` but we ran out of storage - 25GB was not enough to keep xDB index, secondary xDB index for rebuilding and default Sitecore indexes.
- We scaled up Azure Search by adding one more partition - now we have 50GB.
- We restarted `xc-search` app service and started rebuilding of `xDB index` again.
- Secondary index was removed and recreated, logs in `IndexWorker` contain only standard message

> [Information] Starting Xdb Indexer App Domain, Machine: DW1MDWK000006, InstanceName: XConnectIndexer_AppDomain
> [Information] AppInsightsPerformanceCounters Constructor, Instance:XConnectIndexer, Path: App_Data\Diagnostics, CounterFilePattern: *.json
> [Information] Done.

- After 1 hour there was only 1 document in secondary index:

> `{"id": "indexconfiguration", "lastupdated": "2022-05-26T01:43:46.906Z" }.`

- There were no errors in `xc-search` logs and no errors in `IndexWorker` logs.
- We restart `xc-search` app service again, executed `.\XConnectSearchIndexer.exe -rr` again and same story - secondary index removed and recreated, after few minutes 1 document in the index. Same as earlier. Nothing more.
- We let `IndexWorker` to process over night but no change. 1 document in the index.
- I tried again in the morning, same story. Index is being removed from Azure Search and new empty one is being created. But then, only 1 document is there after few minutes `{"id": "indexconfiguration", "lastupdated": "2022-05-26T01:43:46.906Z", "isactivecore": false }` and nothing more

When I run `$filter=id eq 'xdb-rebuild-status'&$select=lastupdated,id,rebuildstate` on primary index, I see:

```
{
  "@search.score": 1,
  "id": "xdb-rebuild-status",
  "lastupdated": "2023-10-03T05:40:59.243Z",
  "rebuildstate": 2
}
```

Last updated matches the time when I triggered rebuild in the morning, `rebuildstate: 2` stands for `starting`.

Does anyone have any idea why `IndexWorker` does not rebuild xDB index after scaling up Azure Search?

Comment: What is shown when you query the rebuild status? $filter=id eq 'xdb-rebuild-status'&$select=id,rebuildstate

Comment: Question updated with the answer to your question

Comment: Might be worth deleting the rebuild document and trying starting process off again - see if it gets stuck at starting status again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54339348/how-to-delete-specific-document-using-id-on-azure-search-rest-api  (sitecore support always asked me to delete the document before rebuilding)

Comment: The fact that you dont see "[Information] Indexing has started" in logs makes me think the process isnt starting because the rebuild document thinks its already started?

Comment: @DeanOBrien after removing 'xdb-rebuild-status' document from main xdb index and triggering rebuild again, it was able to add 21 contacts to secondary xdb index. Can you post the answer about removing 'xdb-rebuild-status' document so I can accept it? I will create another question for indexing being stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is possible that the old 'rebuild document' is still present on your primary core, from your previous failed attempt. Because of this, the process is failing to start, as it believes it is already in a started state.

To remove the document from Azure Search please try issuing a POST request to the following URI with the appropriate service name, index name and api admin key (as a header) filled in:

```
POST https://[service name].search.windows.net/indexes/[index name]/docs/index?api-version=2017-11-11  
Content-Type: application/json   
api-key: [admin key]
```

With the following request body:

```
{  
  "value": [  
    {  
      "@search.action": "delete",  
      "id": "xdb-rebuild-status"  
    }  
  ]  
}
```

Then try restarting the rebuild process.

Credit for the deleting azure document here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54339348/how-to-delete-specific-document-using-id-on-azure-search-rest-api

Comment: Thanks Dean. Removing that document allowed starting the rebuild of xDB index.